# Hours difference in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to find hours spent by each worker on a Pick table using event date (including time) and previous date(including time)
Event date being the end date for worker and previous date as the start date.
I am getting negative figure in some of the return

this is the query:

```
SELECT OEL_UID, NVL(PREVDT, EVENT_TIME) PREVDT, EVENT_TIME, TO_CHAR(ROUND((EVENT_TIME - NVL(PREVDT, EVENT_TIME))*(24),4)) HRSSPENT FROM (SELECT OEL_UID, EVENT_TIME, LAG(EVENT_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY OEL_UID ORDER BY PICKSTATE, EVENT_TIME) AS PREVDT, PICKSTATE, ORDERID FROM DAIDATA.MI_PICK WHERE OEL_CLASS = 'OEL_PICK_SORTED'
```

That's for the Hours spent column return

**OP Comment below**:

I get negative results when previous date is for example `"22-aug-2017 21:23:06"` and event date is for example `"23-aug-2017 00:10:23"` The result then shows like -21.... because the next day has smaller digit in time. I get positive result if the event day had higher digit of time than the previous day.

Comment: Can you provide a sample data and result?

Comment: Well are there any records for which the event date is less than the previous date?

Comment: i get negative results when previous date is for example "22-aug-2017 21:23:06" and event date is for example "23-aug-2017 00:10:23"  The result then shows like -21.... because the next day has smaller digit in time. I get positive result if the event day had higher digit of time than the previous day.

Comment: What is the data type of your columns? Are they both DATE? If so, what you are seeing is hard to believe. Is that the exact formula you are using, or is it wrapped within anything else?

Comment: By the way, the extra info you provided belongs in the question itself. I edited your post to add it there.

Comment: Thanks for editing the question @mathguy. they are both dates

Comment: this is the query: SELECT  OEL_UID,  NVL(PREVDT, EVENT_TIME) PREVDT,   EVENT_TIME,  TO_CHAR(ROUND((EVENT_TIME - NVL(PREVDT, EVENT_TIME))*(24),4)) HRSSPENT  FROM
  (SELECT OEL_UID, EVENT_TIME,
       LAG(EVENT_TIME) OVER (PARTITION BY OEL_UID ORDER BY PICKSTATE, EVENT_TIME) AS PREVDT,
       PICKSTATE,
       ORDERID  FROM DAIDATA.MI_PICK
    WHERE OEL_CLASS = 'OEL_PICK_SORTED'

Comment: You acknowledge @mathguy for editing the question with info from your comments then you  post further info in another comment? Fnord. Comments are for comments; they are especially not for code samples, which are way too hard to read with proper formatting. Please take the hint and **edit your question**.

Answer (score 0):

Try following ---

```
SELECT ROUND(24 * (to_date('23-AUG-2017 00:10:23', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi:ss') -
             to_date('22-AUG-2017 21:23:06', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')),
             4)
  from dual;
```